# Why doesn't reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: work on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I've used `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` on iOS 6, and it ran fine.

```
[self.tableview beginUpdates];
[self.tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableview endUpdates];
```

This calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of the tableview on iOS 6, but, it doesn't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of the tableview on iOS 7, so I can't update the specified cell.

Comment: I got the same issues. Still finding solution.

Comment: you think that it's ios 7 framework bug?

Comment: I found the reason finally. I got indexpath using [TableView indexpathforcell:UITableViewCell]. but, this method always returned null value, so the reloadrowsatindexpath didn't run. I got indexpath following method. CGPoint pos=[UIButton convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:UITableView]; NSIndexPath *indexPath=[UiTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pos]; I hope that this will help you.

Comment: Then post is as an answer @Tianxia

Comment: Do yourself a favour and post the answer.